# Confused by SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

```
USE tempdb;
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#demo_data') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  DROP TABLE #demo_data;
END;

CREATE TABLE #demo_data 
(
    row_id          INT PRIMARY KEY,
    product         VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    customer        VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    measure         VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    value           NUMERIC(6, 1)   NOT NULL,
    valid_from_day  INT NOT NULL,
    valid_to_day    INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #demo_data (
    row_id,
    product,
    customer,
    measure,
    value,
    valid_from_day,
    valid_to_day
)
SELECT 1 row_id, 'Widgets' product, 'Tesco' customer, 'Gross Sales Price' measure, 1 value, 20130101 valid_from_day, 20130401 valid_to_day UNION ALL
SELECT 2 row_id, 'Widgets' product, 'Tesco' customer, 'Gross Sales Price' measure, 1.5 value, 20130301 valid_from_day, 20131231 valid_to_day UNION ALL
SELECT 3 row_id, 'Widgets' product, 'Tesco' customer, 'Gross Sales Price' measure, 2 value, 20130401 valid_from_day, 20150101 valid_to_day UNION ALL
SELECT 4 row_id, 'Widgets' product, 'Tesco' customer, 'Distribution Cost' measure, 5 value, 20130101 valid_from_day, 20130401 valid_to_day UNION ALL
SELECT 5 row_id, 'Widgets' product, 'Tesco' customer, 'Distribution Cost' measure, 6 value, 20130301 valid_from_day, 20140401 valid_to_day UNION ALL
SELECT 6 row_id, 'Widgets' product, 'Tesco' customer, 'Distribution Cost' measure, 7 value, 20131231 valid_from_day, 20150101 valid_to_day UNION ALL
SELECT 7 row_id, 'Widgets' product, 'Asda' customer, 'Gross Sales Price' measure, 100 value, 00000000 valid_from_day, 99999999 valid_to_day UNION ALL
SELECT 8 row_id, 'Widgets' product, 'Asda' customer, 'Gross Sales Price' measure, 200 value, 20131231 valid_from_day, 20150101 valid_to_day UNION ALL
SELECT 9 row_id, 'Widgets' product, 'Asda' customer, 'Distribution Cost' measure, 2 value, 20130301 valid_from_day, 20131231 valid_to_day UNION ALL
SELECT 10 row_id, 'Widgets' product, 'Asda' customer, 'Distribution Cost' measure, 3 value, 20140401 valid_from_day, 20150101 valid_to_day;

SELECT
    row_id,
    product,
    customer,
    measure,
    value,
    valid_from_day,
    valid_to_day
FROM
    #demo_data
ORDER BY 1;
```

Write SQL to identify which pairs of rows have identical Products, Customers and Measures, with overlapping date ranges

-- e.g. rows 1 and 2 have the same product/customer/measure and the overlapping date ranges.

I am confused how do you do comparison within table.. I have some idea about using joins but would it be inner join or just normal join

Comment: This is Oracle?? Looks like SQL Server - can you clarify/update?

Comment: Its SQL server sorry about wrong tag

Comment: First thing you need to do is either store those dates as dates or handle that in your select.

Comment: Looks like a school question (posting the question as B) kinda gave that away), so I won't give a full answer...but a hint is to select the fields you are interested in, group by, and then having (a where on an aggregate) to determine which values show up more than once.

Comment: First tell us what rows are expected in the result... it looks like all but 2 should be included.

Answer (score 0):

The term you are looking for is `self join`.  It works like this:

```
select yourFields
from yourTable t1 join yourTable t2 on t1.something = t2.something
and t1.somethingElse <> t2.somethingElse
```

Comment: ?  Only one table involved, not sure what you are suggesting here.  Group by and having should work, no?

Answer (score 0):

Does the following query work for you? It is an inner join but join to itself

```
select  t1.*,  t2.row_id, t2.valid_from_day, t2.valid_to_day 
from #demo_data t1
inner join #demo_data t2
on t1.product=t2.product and t1.customer = t2.customer and t1.measure = t2.measure
and (    (t2.valid_from_day > t1.valid_from_day) and (t2.valid_from_day < t1.valid_to_day)
      or (t2.valid_to_day > t1.valid_from_day) and (t2.valid_to_day < t1.valid_to_day)
    )
```

Comment: valid day 0-9999999 is returned. These aren't real dates, though.

Comment: @scsimon, what do you mean "valid day 0-9999999 is returned"?

Comment: In your query, the row with valid_from_day = 0 and valid_to_day = 9999999 is returned. The problem is the values aren't stored in date format. Hence, those aren't real dates or even logical values. They should be converted before used as an "overlapping time frame" For example.... `convert(datetime,convert(varchar(10),case when d.valid_from_day = 0 then null else d.valid_from_day end),104) valid_from_day`

Comment: ok, I see what you mean. But I would say the "issue" starts with the original data, we may need to understand what valid_from_day = 0 means before we filter out these results in a query.